# What characters does a new empty NSString contain?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

i created an NSMutableString with the method stringWithCapacity:5
How do i test if characterAtIndex:0 is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty string contains no characters, even if you created it with non-zero capacity. To check if string is empty simply check its length:

```
if ([myString length] == 0){
    // empty
}
```

Moreover, trying to access a character at index which is >= of string's length will result in  `NSRangeException` exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `*WithCapacity` methods that we see on `NSString`, `NSArray`, etc, have nothing to do with pre-populating the contents of the object.  They are simply a means by which you can *suggest* to the object how much it's going to hold.  If you suggest a large enough number, it may use a different storage mechanism than if it were a small number.

So in other words, you could do `[NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:1234567890]` and it give you exactly the same thing as if you had simply done `[NSMutableString string]`, and the `-length` of the resulting object will **always** be 0.

Frankly, the `*WithCapacity` methods are pretty useless. I've *never* found a reason to use them.